# A probability question: Poor Alex

Tags: probability

> Alex remembers all but the last digit of his friend's telephone number. He decides to choose the last digit at random in an attempt to reach him. Given that, Alex has only enough money to make two phone calls, the probability that he dials the right number before running out of money can be expressed as an irreducible fraction p/q.

What I did was--

WLOG let us assume the correct number be 1. Total number of outcomes can be calculated this way
**(0,1)**(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)

**(1)**

(2,0)**(2,1)**(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)(2,9)
(3,0)**(3,1)**(3,2)(3,4)(3,5)(3,6)(3,7)(3,8)(3,9)
(4,0)**(4,1)**(4,2)(4,3)(4,5)(4,6)(4,7)(4,8)(4,9)
(5,0)**(5,1)**(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,6)(5,7)(5,8)(5,9)
(6,0)**(5,1)**(5,3)(5,4)(5,6)(5,7)(5,7)(5,8)(5,9)
(7,0)**(7,1)**(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(7,5)(7,6)(7,8)(7,9)
(8,0)**(8,1)**(8,2)(8,3)(8,4)(8,5)(8,6)(8,7)(8,9)
(9,0)**(9,1)**(9,2)(9,3)(9,4)(9,5)(9,6)(9,7)(9,8)
So total number of outcomes is 82 and total number of favorable outcomes is 10 so my answer is 10/82 or 5/41. But it is not correct. Please help me understand this.....

Comment: Not sure what your calculation is doing.  The probability of guessing the right answer in two tries is $\frac 2{10}=\frac 15$ as the distribution is uniform.

Comment: Your list of numbers is hard to follow.  Clearly there are $10\times 9=90$ ways to choose an ordered pair of unequal digits.  Not sure what your list is...you list $(5,7)$ three times, for example.  And you omit every pair that starts with $1$.

Comment: but when you find the correct answer in your first try you stop

Comment: Sure, but these are still successes, and you don't count them at all.

Comment: @KshitijSingh Yeah, but the the outcomes as you listed them do **not** have the same probability. The probability that you randomly select "1" as first number is $\frac1{10}$. The probability that you randomly select "(5,7)" is $\frac1{100}$. BTW, both you and the other commentors make the assumption that Alex will not repeat the last number from the first try. It sounds reasonable, but is not formally specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex tries the first number. The probability to get it wrong is $9/10$. If he does, he chooses the second number. The probability that he get the second number wrong is $8/9$ (assuming that he does not try to dial the same number expecting a different result). Then the total probability that he gets the number wrong is $$\frac 9{10}\frac89=\frac8{10}$$
That means that he get's it right with probability $2/10=20\%$

Comment: Also, the reason that you got the answer wrong is that not all your cases have the same probability. The one when you dial $1$ on the first try has a different probability than the other cases when you dial $1$ on the second attempt

Answer (score 1):

So you are choosing twice from a set of ten Without replacement. That means the first digit tried, called it A is taken from 0 through 9. The second digit, digit B, should be different, because A has been eliminated.

Let's say the correct digit is X.

What are the chances that neither A or B is X?

That question can be restated: How many ways are there to pick two digits from nine (the ten digits minus X), divided by the number of ways of picking two digits.

There are 36 ways of picking a combination of two distinct digits none of which is X.

There are 45 ways of choosing two distinct digits from all 10.

The probability of failing to get the right digit is 4/5.

So the probability of success is 1/5=1-4/5.

Alternatively:

There's a 1/10 chance of getting it right on the first try.

There's a 9/10 chance of not. We only make the second try if we failed the first. The chances of succeeding the second time around is is 1/9.

So the chances of success is (1/10)(1/1)+(9/10)(1/9)=2/10=1/5, just as via the other method.

This is all based on choosing two distinct digits. If you repeat the same failed digit, the analysis changes a little.

Answer (score 0):

Alex tries two numbers. Then the probability that the correct number belongs to this pair is simply 
$$\frac{2}{10} = 20 \%$$